# Is there any reason for doing back face culling in software?

Tags: javascript, webgl, culling

I, a newbie, have been doing back face culling in javascript for my WebGL app because I didn't know gl.cullFace() existed. Is there any reason to use software-based culling instead of just passing all faces to GPU and let it do the culling?

Answer (score 4):

No.  The GPU has dedicated hardware for the purpose, so it will be far faster, especially compared to Javascript.  (I wouldn't do *anything* that iterates over individual verts / faces in JS!)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, but it depends on your use case and data structures.  You can still get a win if your data is set up so that you can cull *groups* of faces per test, and if doing so doesn't require you to break a batch.  Otherwise just let the GPU do it (especially if you have VBOs available).